# Magento 2: Query For Product Attributes, SKU, SetID, AttributeID

Tags: magento2, database, sql, eav, select

I need a full table query of all my SKUs in the following structure.  I feel I am pretty close but can't seem to figure out the relationships:

- valueID = `eav_attribute_option_value.value`
- AttributeSetID =`eav_attribute_set.attribute_set_id WHERE
  eav_attribute_set.entity_type_id = 4`
- AttributeID =
  `eav_attribute.attribute_id WHERE eav_attribute.entity_type_id = 4`
- SKU =
  `catalog_product_entity.sku`
- value =
  `eav_attribute_option_value.value
  JOIN ON eav_attribute_option.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id`

I believe I need to utilize `eav_attribute_group` table as well but I need to merge all these together somehow I think.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

`

```
valueID   |  AttributeSetID  | AttributeID  | SKU   |  value
   2                3               9        324       Yes
   12               3               11       324       Roast
   3                3               7        324       1
   19               5               10       21069     Jumbo
```